# Format decimal value with unusual rules

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, string-formatting

What's an elegant way to convert a decimal value to string given the following rules?

1. Display all digits before the decimal point.
2. Display a comma invariantly in place of the decimal point.
3. If the portion after the decimal point is nonzero, display only significant digits, but with a minimum of 2.

Examples:

```
decimal       string
------------  ----------
500000        500000,
500000.9      500000,90
500000.90     500000,90
500000.900    500000,90
500000.9000   500000,90
500000.99     500000,99
500000.999    500000,999
500000.9999   500000,9999
```

I can easily display the portion before the decimal point, and the comma, by converting the value to `int`. But it's getting long and tedious handling the different cases for the portion after the decimal point.

If there were a way to specify that I wanted only the digits after the decimal point, but without the decimal point, I'd have this in hand. Something like `String.Format("{0:.00#}", value)`, only don't display the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concise and simple solution ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2SfdnP)):

```
public static string FormatDecimal(decimal d)
{
    string s = d.ToString("0.00##", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).Replace(".", ",");
    if (s.EndsWith(",00", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2); // chop off the "00" after integral values
    return s;
}
```

If your values might have more than four fractional digits, then add additional `#` characters as needed. The format string `0.00##########################`, which has 28 fractional digits, will accommodate all possible `decimal` values.

Comment: The careful use of `InvariantInfo` and `StringComparison.Ordinal` are appreciated.

Comment: P.S. Your answer helped me create this function: `private static int GetNumberOfUsedDecimalPlaces(decimal value) {
   return (value - (int)value).ToString("0.############################", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).Replace(".", "").Length - 1;
}`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call this pretty, but it falls under the category of "it works".

First the implementation,

```
public static class FormatProviderExtensions
{
    public static IFormatProvider GetCustomFormatter(this NumberFormatInfo info, decimal d)
    {
        var truncated = Decimal.Truncate(d);

        if (truncated == d)
        {
            return new NumberFormatInfo
            {
                NumberDecimalDigits = 0,
                NumberDecimalSeparator = info.NumberDecimalSeparator,
                NumberGroupSeparator = info.NumberGroupSeparator
            };
        }

        // The 4th element contains the exponent of 10 used by decimal's 
        // representation - for more information see
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx
        var fractionalDigitsCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(Decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[2];
        return fractionalDigitsCount <= 2
            ? new NumberFormatInfo
            {
                NumberDecimalDigits = 2,
                NumberDecimalSeparator = info.NumberDecimalSeparator,
                NumberGroupSeparator = info.NumberGroupSeparator
            }
            : new NumberFormatInfo
            {
                NumberDecimalDigits = fractionalDigitsCount,
                NumberDecimalSeparator = info.NumberDecimalSeparator,
                NumberGroupSeparator = info.NumberGroupSeparator
        };
    }
}
```

and example usage:

```
var d = new[] { 500000m, 500000.9m, 500000.99m, 500000.999m, 500000.9999m };
var info = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", NumberGroupSeparator = "" };

d.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(info.GetCustomFormatter(x), "{0:N}", x));
});
```

Outputs:

```
500000
500000,90
500000,99
500000,999
500000,9999
```

It grabs the properties we care about from an existing `NumberFormatInfo` and returns a new one with the `NumberDecimalDigits` we want. It's fairly high on the ugly scale, but the use is straightforward enough.

Comment: This looks pretty scary for production code: `BitConverter.GetBytes(Decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[2]`. I understand what you're doing, but it's going to be opaque to some developers. Hmmmm...

Comment: *It's fairly high on the ugly scale* - ;)

Comment: Note that for an input of `500000.9000m`, this code yields `"500000,9000"`. The two extra zeroes at the end may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how elegant you want this to be, but here's a straight-forward way of achieving what you're asking.

```
List<decimal> decimals = new List<decimal>
{
    500000M,
    500000.9M,
    500000.99M,
    500000.999M,
    500000.9999M,
    500000.9000M 
};

foreach (decimal d in decimals)
{
    string dStr = d.ToString();
    if (!dStr.Contains("."))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d + ",");
    }
    else
    {
        // Trim any trailing zeroes after the decimal point
        dStr = dStr.TrimEnd('0');

        string[] pieces = dStr.Split('.');
        if (pieces[1].Length < 2)
        {
            // Ensure 2 significant digits
            pieces[1] = pieces[1].PadRight(2, '0');
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", pieces));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
500000,
500000,90
500000,99
500000,999
500000,9999
500000,90
```

Comment: Note that for an input of `500000.9000m`, this code yields `"500000,9000"`. The two extra zeroes at the end may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Using plain `ToString()` on the decimal may yield strange results with different cultures, yes? If the default culture is one that uses commas for decimal separators, will this work right?